# Import data to the same table on a different server on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am very new to sql server and sql on the whole so I have a question about import/export data. I have the same two tables on two different servers. I do not have access to modify one of them but I can still import data. I tried with a different table and it worked. The server that I have access to modify, let's call it the Dev server and the one which I do not is the Prod server. I am trying to import data into Dev from Prod. The catch with this is that the tables have a primary key and when I am trying to import using sql server import and export wizard it says `cannot insert duplicate key in object`. I tried to exclude the primary key column but then it says `cannot insert null values` (I tried to alter the column to accept null values but it did not work). I would really appreciate some help! Please reach out if you need more information. I tried to explain it on a high level. Thanks!

Comment: Does your Dev table have data in it before you start the import?

Comment: yes it does have some data

Comment: If you import a record from the Prod table that has a primary key id that already exists in the Dev table I believe you will get that duplicate key error. Is starting with an empty Dev table an option for you? At least that's what happens in the flavors of SQL I've worked with (MySQL and Postgres).

Comment: Thank you! I truncated the table and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the destination table you're loading to has a primary key constraint only unique values will be allowed in this column.  It cannot be left null by excluding it from the import either, which true for SQL Server and similar relational databases.  You can either remove the primary key from the destination table, truncate this table prior to loading it, or only import new records via incremental loads.  If you choose to take the incremental loads approach SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) is a good option to handle this.  You mentioned that you're new to SQL Server so I'm guessing you haven't worked with SSIS, but if you're looking to learn more about this the [SSIS Stairway](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) from Andy Leonard is an excellent place to start.

Comment: No problem.  If one of the options I presented helped you complete the import feel free to mark the answer as accepted.  No obligation to do this, just provides clarity for those reading this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that there are some updated records in the one on "Prod" then can you simply import the entire table by itself to your server (as a separate table)
and then UNION them together. This would give you only distinct records from both tables.